# Is this is the correct way to sort a dataframe to get sensible results in ANOVA (aov)?

Tags: r, anova, linguistics, phonetics

I have (theoretically) understood how to interpret results from ANOVA.  I am also aware that the format presented herein is okay while performing LMER tests but since the sample size is small, I am restricted to Anova.

Basically, I want to see if the duration values of variables `C2.dn` show any durational differences when the column 'Consonant' value is 'Singleton' or 'Geminate'? Similarly, if `V1.dn` and `V2.dn` show any durational differences? I have confirmed that these do, by comparing the means of the phonemes.
environment.

The words here, for example, chape, chappe (Row 1,2, Col 'Filename') are minimal pairs where `V1_xsampa` denotes vowel [a/@], `C2_xsampa` denotes consonant [p] or [p:]
and `V2_xsampa` denotes word-ending [e:]. All these phonemes have their numerical (durational) values in their respective columns (`V1.dn`, `C2.dn`, `V2.dn`).

I hope I was clear in making understand. I am new to R. Any help would be great.

**Here is some part of my data:**

```
Filename    Speaker Consonant   Place   Manner  Voicing Beforevowel Gender  V1.dn   V1_xsampa   C2.dn   C2_xsampa   V2.dn   V2_xsampa
AK_chape.TextGrid   1   Singleton   Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   8.1905057   @   8.0042611   p   12.4374436  e:
AK_chappe.TextGrid  1   Geminate    Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   7.4699013   @   16.4554347  p:  11.58376    e:
AK_fati.TextGrid    1   Singleton   Retroflex   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.7985668   @   8.422198    t`  12.3438846  i:
AK_fatti.TextGrid   1   Geminate    Retroflex   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.8838506   @   15.216855   t`: 10.2798309  i:
AK_katha.TextGrid   1   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   7.4477162   @   8.7118953   t_d_h   11.3864323  A:
AK_kute.TextGrid    1   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   7.3607761   U   7.3607761   t_d 13.4668744  e:
AK_kutte.TextGrid   1   Geminate    Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   3.9207081   U   19.7175146  t_d:    13.7452732  e:
AK_saka.TextGrid    1   Singleton   Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.4760697   @   8.2999095   k   11.4918 A:
AK_sakka.TextGrid   1   Geminate    Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   3.9745773   @   20.1309756  k:  11.7704 A:
DS_chape.TextGrid   2   Singleton   Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   5.9323219   @   8.4378223   p   9.0162588   e:
DS_chappe.TextGrid  2   Geminate    Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   5.314411    @   19.3487061  p:  10.7748222  e:
DS_fatti.TextGrid   2   Geminate    Retroflex   Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   4.9362393   @   15.856267   t`: 10.0846991  i:
DS_katha.TextGrid   2   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   3.3544421   @   12.6160778  t_d_h   9.1561501   A:
DS_kattha.TextGrid  2   Geminate    Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   4.7437072   @   18.4249058  t_d_h:  9.9078116   A:
DS_kute.TextGrid    2   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   6.207953    U   8.1345232   t_d 10.9098312  e:
DS_kutte.TextGrid   2   Geminate    Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   4.8676863   U   18.8453944  t_d:    11.3500882  e:
DS_saka.TextGrid    2   Singleton   Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   5.5258074   @   7.9832433   k   10.4823813  A:
DS_sakka.TextGrid   2   Geminate    Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   M   5.3065367   @   17.4189197  k:  10.9633842  A:
MS_chape.TextGrid   3   Singleton   Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   7.0595707   @   8.3394356   p   7.7437615   e:
MS_chappe.TextGrid  3   Geminate    Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.7527086   @   14.4179403  p:  9.6957258   e:
MS_fati.TextGrid    3   Singleton   Retroflex   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.5312929   @   10.1303456  t`  11.9326769  i:
MS_fatti.TextGrid   3   Geminate    Retroflex   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   4.7868677   @   15.4153364  t`: 8.416162    i:
MS_katha.TextGrid   3   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   6.168022    @   10.7629914  t_d_h   9.2727311   A:
MS_kattha.TextGrid  3   Geminate    Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.2644637   @   15.2593152  t_d_h:  9.6438871   A:
MS_kute.TextGrid    3   Singleton   Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.855083    U   6.6463105   t_d 9.0199928   e:
MS_kutte.TextGrid   3   Geminate    Dental/alveolar Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   3.8559587   U   16.2366101  t_d:    9.9234229   e:
MS_saka.TextGrid    3   Singleton   Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.205498    @   7.4699608   k   7.7971282   A:
MS_sakka.TextGrid   3   Geminate    Velar   Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   5.894072    @   13.6923826  k:  9.1358116   A:
NS_chape.TextGrid   4   Singleton   Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   7.4994399   @   8.8423147   p   7.5200995   e: 
NS_chappe.TextGrid  4   Geminate    Bilabial    Stop    Voiceless   Short   F   4.5631368   @   15.3298145  p:  9.4684148   e:
```

EDIT:

**head (df)**

Filename Speaker Consonant           Place Manner   Voicing Beforevowel Gender    V1.dn V1_xsampa     C2.dn C2_xsampa
1  AK_chape.TextGrid       1 Singleton        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 8.190506         @  8.004261         p
2 AK_chappe.TextGrid       1  Geminate        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.469901         @ 16.455435        p:
3   AK_fati.TextGrid       1 Singleton       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 5.798567         @  8.422198        t `4  AK_fatti.TextGrid       1  Geminate       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 5.883851         @ 15.216855       t`:
5  AK_katha.TextGrid       1 Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.447716         @  8.711895     t_d_h
6   AK_kute.TextGrid       1 Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.360776         U  7.360776       t_d
V2.dn V2_xsampa      V1_dn      C2_dn     V2_dn
1 12.43744        e: 0.08190506 0.08004261 0.1243744
2 11.58376        e: 0.07469901 0.16455435 0.1158376
3 12.34388        i: 0.05798567 0.08422198 0.1234388
4 10.27983        i: 0.05883851 0.15216855 0.1027983
5 11.38643        A: 0.07447716 0.08711895 0.1138643
6 13.46687        e: 0.07360776 0.07360776 0.1346687

EDIT2 :
**dput(head(df))**

Filename Speaker Consonant           Place Manner   Voicing Beforevowel Gender    V1.dn V1_xsampa     C2.dn C2_xsampa
1  AK_chape.TextGrid       1 Singleton        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 8.190506         @  8.004261         p
2 AK_chappe.TextGrid       1  Geminate        Bilabial   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.469901         @ 16.455435        p:
3   AK_fati.TextGrid       1 Singleton       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 5.798567         @  8.422198        t `4  AK_fatti.TextGrid       1  Geminate       Retroflex   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 5.883851         @ 15.216855       t`:
5  AK_katha.TextGrid       1 Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.447716         @  8.711895     t_d_h
6   AK_kute.TextGrid       1 Singleton Dental/alveolar   Stop Voiceless       Short      F 7.360776         U  7.360776       t_d
V2.dn V2_xsampa      V1_dn      C2_dn     V2_dn
1 12.43744        e: 0.08190506 0.08004261 0.1243744
2 11.58376        e: 0.07469901 0.16455435 0.1158376
3 12.34388        i: 0.05798567 0.08422198 0.1234388
4 10.27983        i: 0.05883851 0.15216855 0.1027983
5 11.38643        A: 0.07447716 0.08711895 0.1138643
6 13.46687        e: 0.07360776 0.07360776 0.1346687

Comment: what exactly do you mean by sort? Also please provide the output of `dput(data)` instead of pasting your data. Also include the expected results

Comment: @Onyambu By 'sort', I mean the way the dataset is organised. Will anova test recognise it? See the EDIT, please. I have attached head (df)

Comment: You were supposed to paste the output of `dput(head(data))` . And NO, anova does not care whether your data is sorted or not. It compares means of different groups. A mean is not sorted. The results will be the same in a different order

Comment: @Onyambu Since the original dataset has a lot of rows, I preferred to post the head. I am editing the thread with dput ()

Comment: Probably you did not understand when I said `dput`. Run `dput(part_of_your_data shown_above)` then copy the output from the console and paste it here. So far the pasted output is not from the console